# opengl rotation problem

Tags: opengl, translation, rotation, axis

can anyone tell me how to make my model rotate at its own center go gravity in stead of the default (0,0,0) axis?

and my rotation seems to be only going left and right not 360 degree..

Answer (score 9):

If you want to rotate an object around its center, you first have to translate it to the origin, then rotate and translate it back. Since transformation matrices affect your vectors from right to left, you have to code these steps in opposite order.

Here is some pseudocode since I don't know OpenGL routines by heart:

```
PushMatrix();
LoadIdentity();  // Start with a fresh matrix
Translate();     // Move your object to its final destination
Rotate();        // Apply rotations
Draw();          // Draw your object using coordinates relative to the object center
PopMatrix();
```

These matrices get applied:

```
v_t = (I * T * R) * v = (I * (T * (R * v)))
```

So the order is: Rotation, Translation.

---

**EDIT:** An explanation for the equation above.

The transformations rotation, scale and translation affect the *model-view-matrix*. Every 3D point (vector) of your model is multiplied by this matrix to get its final point in 3D space, then it gets multiplied by the *projection matrix* to receive a 2D point (on your 2D screen).

Ignoring the projection stuff, your point transformed by the model-view-matrix is:

```
v_t = MV * v
```

Meaning the original point `v`, multiplied by the model-view-matrix `MV`.

In the code above, we have constructed `MV` by an identity matrix `I`, a translation `T` and a rotation `R`:

```
MV = I * T * R
```

Putting everything together, you see that your point `v` is first affected by the rotation `R`, then the translation `T`, so that your point is rotated before it is translated, just as we wanted it to be:

```
v_t = MV * v = (I * T * R) * v = T * (R * v)
```

Calling Rotate() prior to Translate() would result in:

```
v_t = (I * R * T) * v = R * (T * v)
```

which would be bad: Translated to some point in 3D, then rotated around the origin, leading to some strange distortion in your model.

Comment: I added an explanation for the equation. It is really just some very basic math you will need to understand 3D graphics.

Comment: thanks it works now..
but there's still one problem left, it is not rotating in a circle rather its 180 degree from left to right.. cant tell what's gone wrong?

Comment: isn't the pseudocode backwards? you say the order is rotation, translation, and that sounds right to me... but you Translate(); then Rotate();... i'm very confused.

Comment: @ricket He explains in his answer why the order is that way

Comment: @MartinKonecny Lol, thanks almost 3 years later. Anyway the pseudo code is still wrong, the object should first be `glRotate`ed and then `glTranslate`d. I understand the explanation (perhaps I didn't 3 years ago) but I believe the error might be that OpenGL applies matrices to the left side, so it would end up with `MV = T * R * I`. Then, given that matrix multiplication is associative, the transformation would be correctly applied as `v_t = T * (R * v)`.

Comment: @Ricket: No, `glRotate` performs the operation `M := M * R`, i.e., the rotation matrix is multiplied to the right of the current model-view matrix.  The same is true for the other transformation operations.  Therefore, as I explained, the last transformation operation requested will be applied first to the geometry.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer You're right! I just created a [test](https://gist.github.com/1918222) to clear it up for me. I just got back into OpenGL recently so I have no idea how I've been working without being completely clear on this point. (well, some of my stuff has been with my own vertex shader and matrix functions, which I implemented for left-side multiplication... but now I need to reconsider that!). Thanks for setting the record straight.