# opengl rotate image in place

Tags: opengl, rotation

I am trying to rotate a textured image in place using opengl, however the image 'zooms' around the screen and does not rotate in place.

The code I am using is:

```
gl.glTranslated(textures[2].getHeight()/2, textures[2].getHeight()/2, 0.0);   //origin
gl.glRotated(rotate, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //rotate
gl.glTranslated(-textures[2].getHeight()/2, -textures[2].getHeight()/2, 0.0);//move back
```

However it is not working as I am expecting.

Comment: It's been a while, but if I recall correctly, OpenGL uses columnular vectors so you need to execute your transformations in the opposite order. I.E. Translate to location, rotate, translate to origin.

Comment: This didn't help, thanks for the suggestion though. Still rotates around the view.

Comment: I dont think you need to move it to the origin first, unless you are persisting the results of the translation. I guess you have an object with some vertices defined then you want to rotate and translate. These functions are not cumulative: they do not change the state of your vertices, they operate on a copy of the vertices as they pass through the opengl pipepline. Yoou should be able to just execute glRotated followed by glTranslated which will translate then rotate your object.

Comment: see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685176/opengl-rotation-problem which basically says the same: PushMatrix, loadIdentity, Translate, rotate, draw.